# Como definir um tempo limite da sessão no web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web.config

Pessoal preciso de um timeout pro meu web.config que se o usuário não estiver mexendo no sistema ele expira, se ele estiver mexendo no sistema não expira o tempo. É possível ter algo assim ?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A configuração está correta.

Comment: Sim expira mesmo se o usuario estiver mexendo no sistema

Comment: Mexendo como? O tempo da sessão só é renovado quando o usuário faz um POST ou GET ou PUT, etc, para o servidor. Se ele estiver apenas trabalhando na parte client, a sessão pode cair sim.

Comment: Ha sim entendi, é porque esse sistema não foi eu quem fiz, estou dando manutenção, mais tudo bem!, muito obrigado pela ajuda @MarcellAlves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está confundindo expiração dos **dados da sessão** com **sessão de login**, e elas não são a mesma coisa.

A maneira performática de fazer isso é definindo um atributo que verifique se a `SessionStore` ainda existe ou não. Se não existir, expira a sessão de login:

```
public class VerificarSessaoExpiradaAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext contexto = HttpContext.Current;

        // Verifica se existe um objeto definido na Session
        var objeto = new DadosUsuario();
        objeto = ((DadosUsuario)SessionStore.GetSessionValue("DadosUsuario"));
        if (objeto == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Aí você decora com ele as *Actions* desejadas, ou *Controllers*, ou ainda pode registrar o atributo globalmente:

```
[VerificarSessaoExpirada]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return Index();
}
```

Comment: funcionou Muito Obrigado @CiganiMorrisonMendez